# Inject all Services that implement some Interface

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Simple scenario:

I have multiple Services that implement a common Interface. All those Services are registered within the `bootstrap` method.

Now I'd like to have another Service, which injects all registered Services that implement the common Interface.

i.e.

```
export interface MyInterface {
    foo(): void;
}

export class Service1 implements MyInterface {
    foo() { console.out("bar"); }
}

export class Service2 implements MyInterface {
    foo() { console.out("baz"); }
}

export class CollectorService {
    constructor(services:MyInterface[]) {
        services.forEach(s => s.foo());
    }
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to register your service providers like this:

```
boostrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(MyInterface, { useClass: Service1, multi:true });
  provide(MyInterface, { useClass: Service2, multi:true });
]);
```

This will work only with classes not with interfaces since interfaces don't exist at runtime.

To make it work with interfaces, you need to adapt it:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide('MyInterface', { useClass: Service1, multi:true }),
  provide('MyInterface', { useClass: Service2, multi:true }),
  CollectorService
]);
```

and inject this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class CollectorService {
  constructor(@Inject('MyInterface') services:MyInterface[]) {
    services.forEach(s => s.foo());
  }
}
```

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/HSqOEN?p=preview.

See this link for more details:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Use OpaqueToken, please see the correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35916788/8363

Answer (score 13):

Because interfaces are not available at runtime (only for static checks) interfaces can't be used as toke for DI.

Use a token instead:

(deprecated) 
<strike>https://angular.io/api/core/OpaqueToken</strike>

```ts
var myInterfaceToken = new OpaqueToken('MyInterface');
```

https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

```ts
var myInterfaceToken = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('MyInterface');
```

```ts
// import `myInterfaceToken` to make it available in this file

@NgModule({
  providers: [ 
    { provide: myInterfaceToken, useClass: Service1, multi:true },
    { provide: myInterfaceToken, useClass: Service2, multi:true },
  ],
  boostrap: [AppComponent],
)
class AppComponent {}
```

```ts
// import `myInterfaceToken` to make it available in this file

export class CollectorService {
    constructor(@Inject(myInterfaceToken) services:MyInterface[]) {
        services.forEach(s => s.foo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Using OpaqueToken is the recommended way of providing interface implementations.

Comment: Used `InjectionToken` instead of `OpaqueToken` since the last is deprecated since angular 4.  https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Comment: Using a mix of this answer and [Angular2 How can I Inject all interface implementation to service as list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049643/angular2-how-can-i-inject-all-interface-implementation-to-service-as-list), I managed to make things work. Thanks! To this answer: The provider syntax has changed to something like this: `{ provide: MY_CLASS_INJECTION_TOKEN, useClass: MY_CLASS, multi: true }` and is added to the start module (at least I add it to the start module...)

Comment: @MartinJH glad to hear! Thanks for the hint. It's quite an old answer. I updated it.

Comment: That was a speedy response. Thanks for the effort!