# What is the difference between @Inject vs constructor injection as normal parameter in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm little bit confused in this two scenarios, we mark some classes with @Injectable() decorator so that they become available for injection to different components. I just want to know What is the difference between **@Inject()** and **constructor injection** as normal.

**Scenario 1 - Using @Inject() :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: `
        ....
        {{_service.getName()}}
        ....
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(@Inject(AppService) private _service){}
    ....
}
```

**Scenario 2 - Using as a Normal parameter :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: `
        ....
        {{_service.getName()}}
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private _service:AppService){}
    ....
}
```

Both scenarios are working, is there any difference ? which one should is more preferable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Dependency Injection (DI) correctly in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109555/how-to-use-dependency-injection-di-correctly-in-angular2)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You really should only use `@Inject` for situations where the injectable *token* is not a class. If you are unfamiliar with what a token is, it is basically what Angular uses to recognize what to inject. For example

```
providers: [
  AuthService,
  { provide: Http, useValue: new CustomHttpImpl() }
]
```

Here we have two different providers, the `AuthService` and the `CustomHttpImpl`. With the `AuthService` the token is `AuthService`. This means that we inject `AuthService`, using obviously the `AuthService` type

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
```

With this constructor, Angular knows to look for the `AuthService` with the token `AuthService`.

In the second provider, we provide a `CustomHttpImpl` but this time we use the token `Http`. So we cannot inject `CustomHttpImpl` we need to inject `Http`, since that is the token

```
// this will actually be the CustomHttpImpl, not Angular's Http
constructor(private http: Http)

// error: No provider for CustomHttpImpl
constructor(private http: CustomHttpImpl)
```

So you can tell from this that the tokens are all classes, which is enough for Angular to figure out to how to inject.

But let's say we have a String, or an Array of something we want to inject. We can't tie that to any class token, so we need to create an artificial token

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

let numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
let config = '{ "some": "json", "config": "data" }'

const NUMBERS = new OpaqueToken('app.numbers');
const CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');
```

Now we have tokens for the items we want to inject. When we configure the `providers`, we use those tokens, and when we inject, we `@Inject(TOKEN)`

```
providers: [
  { provide: NUMBERS, useValue: numbers },
  { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config }
]

constructor(@Inject(NUMBERS) numbers: number[], @Inject(CONFIG) config: string)
```

---

### UPDATE

Now, with Angular 4, we should use `InjectionToken` rather than `OpaqueToken`

Comment: nice, I really appreciate your response. I got it.

Comment: BTW - Before the "But let's say we have a String, " i would have add the example of strings tokens ( without OpaqueToken) so they can see where is the problem with collusion. which leads to what you've written about opaques.

Comment: @peeskillet I am a little confused. `OpaqueToken` is a class, and `InjectionToken` extends `OpaqueToken`. Why do I have to use `@Inject` with these?

Comment: @gravidThoughts These are two kind of unrelated things. You should post another question with a code example. It's kind of hard to explain where you're understanding has gone wrong without seeing an example of what you mean

Comment: I discovered recently that there are times when using @Inject actually is worse, not just an alternative. Looking at `@Inject(type) myVar:type` vs.  `myVar:type` in the constructor the former seems to prevent method checking, so I can code `myService.serviceFunc()` and TypeScript doesn't complain if `serviceFunc()` doesn't exist on the service. However, if I use the second method, it does give me an error (as it should) and won't transpile.