# using injectable service to set configuration of APP_BASE_HREF

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm writing an angular 2.1.0 project with typescript 2.0.3.

I created an `app-config` service with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  public config: any = {
    auth0ApiKey: '<API_KEY>',
    auth0Domain: '<DOMAIN>',
    auth0CallbackUrl: '<CALLBACK_URL>',
    appBaseHref: '/'
  }

  constructor() {}

  /* Allows you to update any of the values dynamically */
  set(k: string, v: any): void {
    this.config[k] = v;
  }

  /* Returns the entire config object or just one value if key is provided */
  get(k: string): any {
    return k ? this.config[k] : this.config;
  }
}
```

now I want to use that injectable service on my `app-module.ts` in order to set the `APP_BASE_HREF` provider.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { HelpComponent } from './help/help.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from "@angular/common";
import { MaterialModule } from "@angular/material";
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS }      from "angular2-jwt";
import { RouterModule }  from "@angular/router";
import {AppConfigService} from "app-config.service";

const appConfigService = new AppConfigService();    

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelpComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "",redirectTo:"welcome",pathMatch:"full"},
      { path: "welcome", component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: "help",component: HelpComponent},
      { path: "**",redirectTo:"welcome"}
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:appConfigService.get('appBaseHref')}],bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

so here I initiate the class to a const and use it. is there a way to inject is in a cool and sexy way?

for example for my auth service I defined it in the constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(AppConfigService) appConfigService:AppConfigService)
```

is there a way to do a sexy thing here too? or just to leave it as is?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a factory for the APP_BASE_REF

```
providers: [
  AppConfigService,
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => {
      return config.get('appBaseHref')
    },
    deps: [ AppConfigService ]
  }
]
```

Once you add the `AppConfigService` to the providers, it makes it injectable to both the factory and the auth service. This is generally how it should be done anyway. Later if say the `AppConfigService` needs some dependencies maybe, it will be handled through the injection system.

**See Also:**

- [What is the difference between @Inject vs constructor injection as normal parameter in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019237/2587435) about your use of `@Inject`.

Comment: I don't know how this answer is accepted if this doesn't work. Did you try it before posting?