# `ng test` shows Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BackendService

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below error shown when I ran `ng test` command.

Here is my service spec,

```
describe('BackendService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
            return new Http(backend, options);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        BackendService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([BackendService, MockBackend], (service: BackendService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

);
});

`BackendService.ts` looks like,

```
export class BackendService {
  private baseUrl: string = 'https://foo-backend.appspot.com/_ah/api/default/v1';

  constructor(private http: Http, baseName: string) {
    this.baseUrl = this.baseUrl + baseName;
  }
  .....
}
```

It seems like extra parameter inside the `BackendService` class's constructor causes this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect Angular to know what `baseName` is supposed to be? All constructor parameters need to be obtained from the Injector. And if there is no corresponding token for the parameter, then it can't be looked up.

You can add a token by doing

```
// somewhere in some file
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const BASE_NAME_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken("app.base_name");

// in test class
import { BASE_NAME_TOKEN } from 'where-ever'

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    BackendService,
    { provide: BASE_NAME_TOKEN, useValue: 'whatever-the-base-is' }
  ]
});

// in service constructor
import { Inject } from '@angular/core'
import { BASE_NAME_TOKEN } from 'where-ever'

constructor(http: Http, @Inject(BASE_NAME_TOKEN) baseName: string) {}
```

**See Also:**

- [Dependency Injection Tokens](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens)
- [What is the difference between @Inject vs constructor injection as normal parameter in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40017679/2587435)

Comment: I don't want to change anything in my constructor code. For now, it works totally fine.. But I don't know how to write the testcase.. I have configured the testbed like you did..

Comment: How do you expect Angular to know where to get `baseName` from? There's no magic that's gonna happen. You need to configure the Injector to know how to get it. Otherwise, don't add it as a parameter

Comment: _"But I don't know how to write the testcase"_ What part of the test case do you not know how to write?

Comment: ya, is that we can't pass the constructor's second parameter's value from the testcase? ie, during the BackendService instance creation ..

Comment: You could, by instantiating the service yourself, but that doesn't do anything for the application. The test might pass, then your application will fail. This way is a _must_ if you want the extra parameter

Comment: In the application, you will also need to configure the same in the `@NgModule.providers`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132149/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-peeskillet).