# OpaqueTokens - why do they require @Inject(token) instead of being typed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-opaquetoken

Why do I need to `@Inject(...)` an OpaqueToken, instead of using it like a type?

**Why does this work:**

```
import { AppConstantsToken } from './app.constants.ts';

export class MyApp {
    constructor(@Inject(AppConstantsToken) private config) {
    }
}
```

**And this does not**:

```
import { AppConstantsToken } from './app.constants.ts';

export class MyApp {
    constructor(private config: AppConstantsToken) {
    }
}
```

When I have the following OpaqueToken declared/provided:

**app.constants.ts**:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const APP_CONSTANTS = {
    apiUri: 'appapi.com'
};

export const AppConstantsToken = new OpaqueToken('APPCONSTANTS');

export function provideAppConstants() {
    return APP_CONSTANTS;
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { AppConstantsToken, provideAppConstants } from './app.constants.ts';

@NgModule({
    ...,
    providers: [
        { provide AppConstantsToken, useFactory: provideAppConstants }
    ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "instead of being typed"? I think this might help you understand whatever it is you are not understanding.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40019237/2587435

Comment: `AppConstantsToken` is not a `Type`, it’s a value which means typeScript cannot compile it.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://toddmotto.com/angular-dependency-injection#inject

Comment: The cited answer really covers this. You can't do something like `config: AppConstantsToken` in TS because `config` isn't `AppConstantsToken` type. It is `Object`.

Comment: I.e.: `private config: AppConstantsToken` - TypeScript complains `Cannot find name 'AppConstantsToken'`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Question sufficiently answered.