# Angular2 How can I Inject all interface implementation to service as list?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm learning Angular2 with Typescript and I have a problem.

I have two classe that imprements same interface. How can I inject them to a service as a list ?

I read about opaquetoken https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#opaquetoken

But I don't know if I need to use it and how to use it.

```
export interface CheckerInterface {
    check(text : string) : boolean
}

export class Checker1 implements CheckerInterface {
    check(text : string) : boolean {
    //do something 
    return true;
}

export class Checker2 implements CheckerInterface {
    check(text : string) : boolean {
    //do something 
    return true;
}

@Injectable()
export class Service {

  constructor(private checkers: CheckerInterface[]) {  //??
      checkers.foreach( checker => checker.check(somestring));
  }

}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: why you want to implement an interface? Why you are looking to injecting it into service ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to either add the array as a provider, or use `multi: true` in the `provider` configuration.

```
export const CHECKERS = new OpaqueToken('one');

@NgModule({
  providers: [
     { provide: CHECKERS, useValue: [new Checker1(), new Checker2()] },
  ]
})
```

Or

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
     { provide: CHECKERS, useClass: Checker1, multi: true },
     { provide: CHECKERS, useClass: Checker2, multi: true },
  ]
})
```

The second one is probably preferable, as you let Angular create them, allowing them to be injected with their own dependencies if needed.

Then you just need to use the `CHECKERS` token when you inject

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CHECKERS } from './wherever';

constructor(@Inject(CHECKERS) private checkers: CheckerInterface[]) {
```

### UPDATE

As of Angular 4, [`InjectionToken`](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) is used instead of `OpaqueToken`

```
export const CHECKERS = new InjectionToken<CheckerInterface>('CheckerInterface');
```

Comment: This is clear and easy for me but... This might me stupid question... I got my providers in app.module.ts and I added this two lines to my other providers . I also added const CHECKERS = new OpaqueToken('checkers'); line. But constructor(@Inject(CHECKERS) [...]  is in another file and it 'Cannot find name CHECKERS'. I'm just at begginer level ;|

Comment: You need to export it, then import it. I updated my answer

Comment: Well... I learned a lot today. Thanks! But I wonder if I did something wrong because i get Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Service: (?).

Comment: This answer helped me solved my problem when combined with the answer from @Günter Zöchbauer at [Inject all Services that implement some Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916542/inject-all-services-that-implement-some-interface/35916788#35916788). This answer needs to change  the deprecated OpaqueToken with the new [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken).